# XQUERY() for SQL Assistance

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I have a table that stores the data in XML. There are two nodes that I need the data from.

Example script:

```
select MARKUP_MESSAGE  
from TABLE_NAME 
where row_uno = 6599064
```

Example result:

```
<PrebillMarkup xmlns="clr-namespace:Aderant.Query.ViewModels;assembly=Aderant.Query" 
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">    
    <PrebillMarkup.NewValues>      
        <x:String x:Key="Narrative" xml:space="preserve">Review of policies against previous policies</x:String>    
    </PrebillMarkup.NewValues>    
    <PrebillMarkup.OriginalValues>      
        <x:String x:Key="Narrative" xml:space="preserve">Review of policies against previous policies sdffddgsgfdfdg</x:String>    
    </PrebillMarkup.OriginalValues>  
</PrebillMarkup>
```

I have two nodes `<PrebillMarkup.NewValues>` and `<PrebillMarkup.OriginalValues>`.

I want to be able to pull out the `x:String` from the `<PrebillMarkup.NewValues>` to read  "Review of additional policies - test"

So when I run the statement:

```
select MARKUP_MESSAGE  
from TABLE_NAME 
where row_uno = 6599064
```

the result will be "Review of additional policies - test"

Or if I do another query to pull out the text value for

```
<x:String x:Key="Narrative" xml:space="preserve">
```

Any ideas on how to do this as each time I try I'm getting more XML data but I need just plain text.

Thanks all

SQL version:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 - 15.0.4280.7 (X64)   
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64>
```

Comment: What were those attempts? You forgot to includes them. Seems like you just need to declare your namespace(s) and you can get the data with the `nodes` and `value` methods.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is not provided. So, I am shooting from the hip.

As @ThomA already pointed out, you need to declare and use namespaces.

XQuery `.nodes()` and `.value()` methods do the job to shred the XML into rectangular/relational format.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (row_uno INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Markup_Message XML);
INSERT @tbl (Markup_Message) VALUES
(N'<PrebillMarkup xmlns="clr-namespace:Aderant.Query.ViewModels;assembly=Aderant.Query"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <PrebillMarkup.NewValues>
        <x:String x:Key="Narrative" xml:space="preserve">Review of policies against previous policies</x:String>
    </PrebillMarkup.NewValues>
    <PrebillMarkup.OriginalValues>
        <x:String x:Key="Narrative" xml:space="preserve">Review of policies against previous policies sdffddgsgfdfdg</x:String>
    </PrebillMarkup.OriginalValues>
</PrebillMarkup>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'clr-namespace:Aderant.Query.ViewModels;assembly=Aderant.Query',
                   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' AS x)
SELECT t.row_uno
    , c.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(128)') AS element_name
    , c.value('(x:String/@x:Key)[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)') AS attribute_key
    , c.value('(x:String/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)') AS string_value
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY Markup_Message.nodes('/PrebillMarkup/*') AS t1(c)
WHERE row_uno = 1;
```

**Output**

| row_uno | element_name | attribute_key | string_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PrebillMarkup.NewValues | Narrative | Review of policies against previous policies |
| 1 | PrebillMarkup.OriginalValues | Narrative | Review of policies against previous policies sdffddgsgfdfdg |

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for.  Typically I'm pulling this out for one bill number and there may be 30 plus markup_message rows.  I've now managed to add the remainder of the edits, pop it into a stored procedure, the pull the string on to the tax invoice.  Thanks so much, you've saved me so much time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand what you're trying to do - but here's one possible approach:

```
-- define table - here, for simplicity's sake, just a table variable
DECLARE @table_name TABLE 
                    (
                        ID INT NOT NULL,
                        Markup_Message XML
                    )

-- insert data into table
INSERT INTO @table_name (ID, Markup_Message)
VALUES (1, '<PrebillMarkup xmlns="clr-namespace:Aderant.Query.ViewModels;assembly=Aderant.Query" 
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">    
    <PrebillMarkup.NewValues>      
        <x:String x:Key="Narrative" xml:space="preserve">Review of policies against previous policies</x:String>    
    </PrebillMarkup.NewValues>    
    <PrebillMarkup.OriginalValues>      
        <x:String x:Key="Narrative" xml:space="preserve">Review of policies against previous policies sdffddgsgfdfdg</x:String>    
    </PrebillMarkup.OriginalValues>  
</PrebillMarkup>');

-- query the data, using XQuery, to extract the "x:String" 
-- from the <PrebillMarkup.NewValues> node
--
-- IMPORTANT: you need to respect and include the XML Namespaces
-- defined in your XML document into your query!
--
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'clr-namespace:Aderant.Query.ViewModels;assembly=Aderant.Query',
                   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' AS x)
SELECT
    Markup_Message.value('(/PrebillMarkup/PrebillMarkup.NewValues/x:String/text())[1]', 'varchar(500)')
FROM
    @table_name
WHERE
    ID = 1;
```

Running this, I get the result:

```
(no column name)
----------------------------------------------
Review of policies against previous policies
```

Comment: Thanks marc_s, that was a great option as well.